# Is there a simpler way to return edge values when using contract_vertices() and community functions in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph with communities. I would like edge weights for all the edges between one community and all other nodes in the graph. I need the individual weights because I'd like to perform calculations on each edge weight (square them, for what it's worth). I've gotten some distance with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375719/extract-a-list-of-edges-between-community-nodes-and-other-nodes-for-each-communi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692817/generating-a-community-graph-in-igraph) but it's really awkward.

This is what I've tried:

```r
library(igraph)

## create example graph
g1 <- graph.full(5)
V(g1)$name <- 1:5
g2 <- graph.full(5)
V(g2)$name <- 6:10
g3 <- graph.ring(5)
V(g3)$name <- 11:15
g <- g1 %du% g2 %du% g3 + edge('1', '6') + edge('1', '11')

E(g)$weight <- c(1:27)

# determine community structure
cl <- cluster_louvain(g)
V(g)$name <- membership(cl)

# contract the graph
cg <- contract.vertices(graph = g,
                        mapping = membership(cl))
cg2 <- simplify(cg)
```

contract.vertices() retains edge attributes. To extract edge weights between a community and all other nodes (excluding within community nodes) and perform a bit of calculation on the weights, I can do this:

```r
# edges weights linking community 1 and community 2
E(cg)[ V(cg)[1] %--% V(cg)[2]]$weight
#> [1] 1 2 3 4

# edges weights linking community 1 and community 3
E(cg)[ V(cg)[1] %--% V(cg)[3]]$weight
#> [1] 26

bind_rows(
 tibble(one_two_edges = E(cg)[ V(cg)[2] %--% V(cg)[1]]$weight) %>%
  mutate(summed_square_edge_weight = one_two_edges^2) %>%
  summarize_all(sum) %>%
  select(-one_two_edges)
 ,
 tibble(one_three_edges = E(cg)[ V(cg)[1] %--% V(cg)[3]]$weight) %>%
  mutate(summed_square_edge_weight = one_three_edges^2) %>%
  summarize_all(sum) %>%
  select(-one_three_edges)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 1
#>   summed_square_edge_weight
#>                       <dbl>
#> 1                        30
#> 2                       676
```

I know this is very clunky, but I'm stumped on how to simplify it. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```r
tibble(
community_links = c("com_1_to_com_2", "com_1_to_com_3"),
summed_square_edge_weight = c(30, 676))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   community_links summed_square_edge_weight
#>   <chr>                               <dbl>
#> 1 com_1_to_com_2                         30
#> 2 com_1_to_com_3                        676
```

Suggestions about how to get these results more simply?

<sup>Created on 2022-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually approaching it, and I think `combn` could help you out there

```
do.call(
    rbind,
    combn(
        vcount(cg),
        2,
        function(k) {
            data.frame(
                community_links = paste0(paste0("com_", k), collapse = "_to_"),
                summed_square_edge_weight = sum((E(cg)[V(cg)[k[1]] %--% V(cg)[k[2]]]$weight)^2)
            )
        },
        simplify = FALSE
    )
)
```

which gives

```
  community_links summed_square_edge_weight
1  com_1_to_com_2                        30
2  com_1_to_com_3                       676
3  com_2_to_com_3                         0
```

Answer (score 1):

After poking around in `igraph` a bit more, it turns out this is possible: `igraph::get.data.frame()`  returns an edgelist with the edge weights of the contracted vertices (here coerced with `tibble::as_tibble()`. Turns out the `vertex.attr.comb()` argument in the `contract.vertices()` function needs to be set to something that retains the name vertex attribute assigned earlier. I didn't sum the squares just to show the returned values.

```
 cg <- contract.vertices(graph = g,
                    mapping = membership(cl),
                    vertex.attr.comb = "min")
 
 as_tibble(as_long_data_frame(cg),
          .name_repair = "universal") %>%
 select(from:weight) %>%
 filter(from != to) %>% 
 mutate(sq_weight = weight^2)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>    from    to weight sq_weight
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1     2      1         1
#> 2     1     2      2         4
#> 3     1     2      3         9
#> 4     1     2      4        16
#> 5     1     3     26       676
```

Comment: Greate follow-up, +1! I think this is more efficient.